# Decide implementation at runtime using dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a scenario where I need to get an implementation not known until runtime.
My approach so far is by creating a service class (to abstract the logic from the classes that use them).
The clients and the service is registered with DI. The calling classes only requests Service.

Below are two different approaches (simplified):

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IClient client1;
    private readonly IClient client2;

    public Service(Client1 client1, Client2 client2)
    {
        this.client1 = client1;
        this.client2 = client2;
    }

    public Data GetData(string client, string something)
    {
        if (client == "client1")
            return this.client1.GetData(something);

        return this.client2.GetData(something);
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public Service(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Data GetData(string client, string something)
    {
        if (client == "client1")
            return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Client1>().GetData(something);

        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Client2>().GetData(something);
    }
}
```

And then this is used by calling:
`service.GetData("client1", ...)`

Are any of these alternatives a good approach for doing this? Is one preferable over the other?

Comment: How and when is this changed? If this can be determined during startup (this is also runtime) you can just register with DI and not care about anything. Or is this something that changes continuously during runtime? In the last case I would probably end up creating a factory for it and then injecting that factory wherever the different implementations could be used.

Comment: The first shouldn't work (you inject classes not interfaces), and the second follows the service-locator anti-pattern, so I'd use none of them. A better approach depends on how is "client" obtained in the call, but I'd go for a factory-like approach

Comment: Why would a class instead of an interface stop DI? It depends on how it's registered.

Comment: When you say "at runtime", do you mean that the decision is fixed on application start, or is this choice being made dynamically for every request you handle after the application has started?

Comment: With runtime I meant it (can) change dynamically for every request.

Comment: Have you considered using `Lazy` to at least only pay the instantiation cost when necessary? Or metadata? https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#metadata-interrogation-meta-b-meta-b-x Or keyed service lookup? https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#keyed-service-lookup-iindex-x-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all cases, option 2 is a bad one.

- The service locator pattern is widely considered to be an antipattern. It may solve the problem at hand but it creates many other problems down the line.
- You're letting your consumer decide which client to use, which effectively negates the idea of letting the service define its own dependency using the constructor.
- Magic strings are never desirable. If your consumer is deciding the client anyway, then it makes no sense for them to have to use some magic string to select the correct client. It's considerably less error prone to let them pass the client itself - but then `Service` isn't relying on the DI framework for the client object, which may defeat the purpose of your setup.

---

**IF** the choice of client is made dynamically every time `GetData()` is called, then option 1 is a valid approach.

Though I would suggest using more descriptive names than "client1" and "client2" where possible.

---

**IF** the choice of client is dynamic, but remains fixed after application start, meaning that all calls to `GetData()` during the same runtime will be handled by the same client, then it's better to choose this client when registering your dependencies:

```
// Startup.cs

if( /* selection criteria */)
{
    services.AddScoped<IClient, Client1>();
}
else
{
    services.AddScoped<IClient, Client2>();
}

// Service.cs

public class Service
{
    private readonly IClient client;

    public Service(IClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Data GetData(string something)
    {
        return this.client.GetData(something);
    }
}
```

Though I would suggest using more descriptive names than "client1" and "client2" where possible.

Note that your selection criteria can be whatever you want them to be, e.g. an app config value, database value, environment value, compilation type (debug/release), ... The world is your oyster.

---

Also evaluate whether you'd be better off implementing an additional abstraction that can decide which client to redirect to (e.g. a `ClientFactory` or `ClientRouter`). This isn't always necessary, but if your requirements are less-than-trivial the abstraction may help keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

Both have drawbacks:

- Version #1 always gets two instantiated clients. If instantiation is a heavy process, this is not good.
- Version #2 hides it's dependencies. That is a well-known anti-pattern.

The perfect solution would be to inject an `IClient1Factory` and an `IClient2Factory` and call their factory create methods when needed. That means you still instantiate only one, not both, but you do not hide the dependencies.

As always there is no perfect solution, you now obviously need to write and maintain those two factories. Make sure it's worth it. If Client1/Client2 class instantiation is just a simple `new` with nothing happening in the constructor, you may want to opt for the simpler Version #1 approach. If it's simple and it works, don't wrap it in too many pattern layers. Only use them if you need them.

Comment: If instantiation of clients is a heavy process, a factory that presumably repeatedly spawns these clients (because why else use a factory which is tied to a specific client type?) is going to be an inferior solution to instantiating the client(s) once during the `Service` instantiation. The suggestion of using two factories here clashes with the first bullet point. If the factory which is tied to a specific client type spawns its client only once, then there's little reason to having it (note: a factory which can spawn any type of client would have a purpose, but then it's a service locator)

Comment: IMO, factories are [hardly ever the right abstraction](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/).

Comment: @Flater You seem to assume that a service is only spawned once. The factory can have a different lifetime than the service. It might be able to cache parts of the heavy lifting over multiple service instances. Or maybe not, maybe it conjures pink elephants out of thin air. The point is that we both don't know what such a factory would do, so it's kinda moot to discuss it. It opens up options you otherwise don't have. And I think I explicitly wrote "Only use them if you need them." because I'm not a big fan either, but it's still the best way if you *need* those options.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do, is to inject **ClientX** trought an interface for more flexibility as shown in code below :

```
public class Service<T> where T : IClient
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public Service(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Data GetData<T>(string something)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>().GetData(something);
    }
}
```